# CDI+OSGI: bundle packages scope

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, weld, pax

I use javase and solution osgi (felix)+cdi(weld)+paxcdi. I have two bundles A and B. Bundle B is a lib bundle.

In bundle A I have one class and one package.

```
package com.example.firstpackage;
import com.example.secondpackage.Class2;
public class Class1{
   @Inject
   private Class2 class2;
}
```

In bundle B I have two classes and two packages

```
package com.example.secondpackage;
import com.example.thirdpackage.Class3;
public class Class2{
   @Inject
   private Class3 class3;
}
```

and

```
package com.example.thirdpackage;
public class Class3{
   ....
}
```

I install and start both bundles.

The problem - pax (or weld) for injecting in classes of bundle A scans only those packages which are imported for classes IN bundle A. In my example - CDI
for injecting in Class1 Class2 will scan com.example.secondpackage of bundle B. However, it will throw exception as Class2 needs Class3 but com.example.thirdpackage is not scanned for bundle A (as it's not imported!!!). com.example.thirdpackage is only scanned for bundle B but, as I understand every bundles for cdi has its own scope. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't change your system design, all you can do is to export `thirdpackage` from `B` and to import it into `A`.

To achieve better encapsulation, you could factor out a service interface `IClass2` implemented by `Class2`, make this class an `@OsgiServiceProvider` and use

```
@Inject @OsgiService
private IClass2 class2;
```

in `Class1`.

Comment: +1 for the alternative suggestion since the original design may be fine using CDI in JEE but is definitively not the way to do it in OSGi.